# Как сохранить отображение на 1280px?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Есть сайт test15.host1659821.hostland.pro и два изображения, как отображается сайт на 1280 и 1900.

Нужно, чтобы на любом размере экрана сайт выглядел также, как и на 1900. Для верстки использовался бутстрап.

Как можно сохранить отображение сайта как в 1900 на 1280 и меньших разрешениях?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: увидел тёлочку на час

Comment: А просто добавить `min-width: 1900px;`?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о фоновом изображении, то задайте `background-size:100%` или `width:100%`, если картинка подложена в виде `<img>`.

Если же вам надо сайт полностью вписывать в ширину окна браузера, то верстайте все, ориентируясь на габариты вьюпорта (задавайте размеры в vw).

Удачи в подгонке размеров шрифтов ;)